# 3D Extension of a Fun Geometric Series Puzzle

Tags: calculus, puzzle, vectors, quaternions

After being inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872942/fun-geometric-series-puzzle), and in particular Semiclassical's excellent [response](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/872949/166413) and generalisation, I thought of another generalisation to a 3-dimensional plane.:

> Suppose you start at at some point in space, and then you move a
>   distance $a$ meters from that point. Then, you rotate at an angle of
>   elevation $\phi$ and azimuthal angle $\theta$ relative to your current
>   position, and move forward $ar$ meters from that point, for $|r|<1$.
>   You then rotate and move $ar^2$, then $ar^3$, and so forth. As you
>   keep doing this ad infinitum, how far are you from your starting
>   point?

Here's my idea for it. Suppose that we start at the point $(0,0,0)$ and our first movement takes us to $(0,0,a)$. The path to the next point is along the vector $(ar\sin\theta\sin\phi,ar\sin\theta\cos\phi,ar\cos\theta)$, the next one is along the vector $(ar^2\sin2\theta\sin2\phi,ar^2\sin2\theta\cos2\phi,ar^2\cos2\theta)$, and so forth. Hence, the distance from the origin is the magnitude
$$a\left\|\sum_{k=0}^\infty\pmatrix{r^k\sin k\theta\sin k\phi\\r^k\sin k\theta\cos k\phi\\r^ k\cos k\theta}\right\|$$
which unfortunately doesn't turn out very nice. Is there a simpler way to do this? Based on Semiclassical's response above, I imagine one could do it with quaternions, but I have no expericence with those. Is there an elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure about your modelisation, or perhaps I don't read correctly your "rotate at an angle of elevation $\phi$ and azimutal angle $\theta$ relative to your current position". In particular, take $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$. It is in any case a very interesting puzzle.

Comment: When I say that I mean as in the description given [here][1] of azimuthal angle and angle of elevation, and by current position I mean taking your current direction to be the x-axis for the angles. If I find a better way to phrase that I'll edit that, but that was the best I got

  [1]:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system

Comment: I get it. Since I am a physicist, I have a different convention ($\theta$ and $\phi$ swapped...). No It is clearer in my mind. However, there is still an inkling of doubt relative to the cumulative effect of the $\theta$ in my mind. Since you take it from the $z$ axis, there is no accumulation of the angle relative to the initial $xy$ plane, isn't it? If the $\theta$ angle was relative to the $xy$ plane, this would be the case.

Answer (score 1):

### Introduction

You may find the solution elegant; the results, probably not.

A few results are needed in order to perform the summation of the vectors. Trigonometric identities we will need are:

$\sin{k\theta}\ \sin{k\phi} = \dfrac{\cos(k\theta-k\phi) - \cos(k\theta+k\phi)}{2} \tag{1}$

$\sin{k\theta}\ \cos{k\phi} = \dfrac{\sin(k\theta-k\phi) + \sin(k\theta+k\phi)}{2} \tag{2}$

Euler's formula for imaginary exponentials:

$e^{ix} = \cos{x} + i\ \sin{x}, \cos{x} = \operatorname{Re}(e^{ix}), \sin{x} = \operatorname{Im}(e^{ix})\ \ (\forall x \in \mathbb{R}) \tag{3}$

Also, for integer values of $k$ (basically de Moivre's formula)

$(e^{ix})^k = e^{ikx} = e^{i(kx)} = \cos{kx} + i\ \sin{kx}\ \ (\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}) \tag{4}$

Finally, 
$\Large\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\normalsize{z^k} = \dfrac{1}{1-z}\ \text{ for } |z|<1, z \in \mathbb{C} \tag{5}$

### Summation of Components

#### Easiest First ($v_3$)

By (3), (4), (5) provided $|r|<1$ we have

$v_3 = \Large\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\normalsize{r^k\cos k\theta} = \Large\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\normalsize{r^k \operatorname{Re}(e^{ik\theta})} = \operatorname{Re}\Bigg(\Large\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\normalsize{(re^{i\theta})^k}\Bigg) = \operatorname{Re}\Bigg(\normalsize{\dfrac{1}{1-re^{i\theta}}}\Bigg)$ so

$v_3 = \operatorname{Re}\Bigg(\normalsize{\dfrac{1}{(1-r\cos\theta)-ir\sin\theta}}\Bigg) = \operatorname{Re}\Bigg(\normalsize{\dfrac{(1-r\cos\theta)+ir\sin\theta}{(1-r\cos\theta)^2+r^2\sin^2\theta}}\Bigg)$

Hence
$v_3 = \dfrac{1 - r\cos\theta}{1+r^2-2r\cos\theta} \tag{6}$

#### Then $v_1$

By (1) we have

$v_1 = \Large\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\normalsize{r^k\sin k\theta\sin k\phi} = \dfrac{1}{2}\Large\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\normalsize{r^k\cos(k(\theta-\phi))} + \dfrac{1}{2}\Large\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\normalsize{r^k\cos(k(\theta+\phi))}$

which consists of two terms of the same form as $v_3$, so can be expressed via (6) as

$v_1 = \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{1 - r\cos(\theta-\phi)}{1+r^2-2r\cos(\theta-\phi)} - \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{1 - r\cos(\theta+\phi)}{1+r^2-2r\cos(\theta+\phi)} \tag{7}$

This may or may not reduce nicely. That may depend on your standard for "nicely".

#### And a Bit More Work for $v_2$

First we establish an identity for the sum of sines (call this $s$).
Similar to before we have

$s = \Large\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\normalsize{r^k\sin k\theta} = \Large\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\normalsize{r^k \operatorname{Im}(e^{ik\theta})} = \dots = \operatorname{Im}\Bigg(\normalsize{\dfrac{(1-r\cos\theta)+ir\sin\theta}{(1-r\cos\theta)^2+r^2\sin^2\theta}}\Bigg)$

Hence
$s = \dfrac{r\sin\theta}{1+r^2-2r\cos\theta} \tag{8}$

---

By (2) we have

$v_2 = \Large\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\normalsize{r^k\sin k\theta\cos k\phi} = \dfrac{1}{2}\Large\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\normalsize{r^k\sin(k(\theta-\phi))} + \dfrac{1}{2}\Large\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\normalsize{r^k\sin(k(\theta+\phi))}$

Now applying (8) to each of the terms:

$v_2 = \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{r\sin(\theta-\phi)}{1+r^2-2r\cos(\theta-\phi)} + \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{r\sin(\theta+\phi)}{1+r^2-2r\cos(\theta+\phi)} \tag{9}$