# The mystik spiral(challenge)

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Still one of my favorite problems.
Feel free to attempt to solve it.

1. Start at a 0,0
2. Travel along the x axis in the positive direction a distance of 1
3. Turn 90 degrees counterclockwise
4. go forward 1/2 of the distance of the previous step
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 forever.
6. how far from the origin to you end up?

Bonus points for finding an equation for

1.Start at a 0,0

2.travel along the x axis in the positive direction a distance of A

3. Turn θ degrees counterclockwise
4. go forward B times the previous distance walked
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 forever.
6. how far from the origin to you end up?

Comment: That's not a challenge, not here.

Comment: While this has already been closed on other grounds, it's also worth noting that it's a duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/872942/137524

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use complex numbers.

The final position is, supposing $1>B\ge 0$,

$$A+ABe^{i\theta}+AB^2e^{2i\theta}+\cdots$$
$$=A(1+Be^{i\theta}+B^2e^{2i\theta}+\cdots)$$
$$=A\frac{1}{1-Be^{i\theta}}$$

The distance is
$$\left|\frac{A}{1-Be^{i\theta}}\right|=\frac{A}{\sqrt{1-2B\cos\theta+B^2}}$$

For $A=1$, $B=1/2$, $\theta=\pi/2$, the distance is
$$\left|\frac{1}{1-\frac{i}{2}}\right|=\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$$

Comment: Man, i did this back in ninth grade. My answer was was more complicated, I did not eve know what a complex number was back then

Comment: I am interested to know your method without using complex numbers.

Comment: I actually made an entire YouTube video series about it, because it's fairly complicated, The Mystic spiral: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6GmULYxljW8Wv8s2A8Xbe8ztj-emh4gh

Comment: To be complete: $|\frac1{1-i/2}|=\frac2{\sqrt5}=\frac{2\sqrt5}5$.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Thanks!

Comment: And $\left\lvert\dfrac A{1-Be^{i\theta}}\right\rvert=\dfrac A{\sqrt{B^2-2B\cos\theta+1}}$, I believe. (You get that by multiplying $\dfrac A{1-Be^{i\theta}}$ by its conjugate, $\dfrac A{1-Be^{-i\theta}}$, and taking the square root.)